# Loading PHP results in with JQUERY and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So I am creating a twitter search feature that will allow me to search for anything in twitter. It works but I am issues with the getting the results to show up the way I want. I actually want it to display with bootstrap and some jquery by displaying first with the .length of the results so that it shows me how many of those items are as of today and if I click on the number should show the results.

This is the php

```
strong text    if ($sel=="Twitter"){if (isset($q)) {
    twit($q);
} else {
    echo '<div class="span10" style="background-color:#ffffff;">';
    echo '<div class="span10" style="margin:10px">';
    echo '<span class="label label-info"><h5>Please Enter A Search Term</h5></span>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This is my results in PHP

```
if ($getmenu == 'Twitter') {
  echo '<li style="margin-top:2px;font-weight:bold;"><a class="current animated shake" href="search.php?q=' .$getq . '&scl=Twitter"><img src="images/icons/twitter.png"> Twitter</a></li>';
}
```

The issue is I have no clue how to tell it to display with Jquery, I have been searching and playing with different code like JSON Loading the php file to a div but thats not working, even tried AJAX.

Comment: Not sure if it would help but heres an example.
So say I want to search twitter for anyone with the name Jason. 
Instead of it showing just the results I would like to see how many there are for todays date and if I click that number than it would show me the results.

Comment: Since the php is a server side code, i think you should call your results php using ajax and the print the results using jquery. And it would be cool if you can state your call order in some way. maybe you should explain what you are trying to achieve by giving the php file names too

Answer (score 0):

1- In your html define call method.

```
<div id="yourDiv" onclick="getSomeData()">
```

2- Make post or get call to your service with jquery in your js. And get Data.

```
function getSomeData(){
var url = "service/yourService.php";
    $.post(url,{data:data})
    .done(function(data){
       //this data is your call result.
       //do something
       changeYourDiv(data);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log('fail');
    });

}
```

3- Create your gui function in js to change your div.

```
function changeYourDiv(data){
    $('#yourDiv').append(data);
}
```